# Chinese for "vote-up", "vote-down" and "vote to close"

Tags: word-requests, terminology

What are the correct Chinese words to use for the following:

- Vote-up
- Vote-down
- Vote to close

I assume these will have been included in certain social platforms in China.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Usually you would use:

(投)赞成(票)   Vote-up

(投)反对(票)   Vote-down

投关闭票       Vote to close

However, when used on internet, especially sites like SE, probably the following is more suitable:

顶 - literally means bump  (Vote-up)

踩 - literally means tread  (Vote-down)

叉 - literally means X (cross), have the implication of closing.  (Vote to close)

Comment: how about 叉（cha1）？

Comment: @Huang Usually vote-up and vote-down should be a pair. What would you use for vote-up if you use 叉 for vote-down? Maybe 勾? :)

Comment: sorry,I mean to use 叉 for "vote to close", so that we use a single character for every choice. I think this looks prettier.

Comment: @Huang I agree. I've edited the answer. Thanks. :)

Comment: We also use 推 for vote-up and 噓 for vote-down in Taiwan, due to the largest BBS site (PTT) we have.